# Can I use Redis as a scheduled queue, reacting on key expiration events

Tags: java, redis, queue, schedule

I'm thinking of using Redis in my Java application, instead of Quartz.

The idea is to reuse Redis key expiration mechanism, as a job trigger. With following workflow:

1. Create a key in Redis with expiration time as scheduled time
2. Listen for key expiration in Java.
3. When key expires trigger a job, defined by key name.

Has anyone tried such a use case?

Comment: I'd be weary of this approach because 1) Redis doesn't proactively expire keys so the behavior you'll get could be not what you're expecting and 2) keyspace notifications have no assurance of being received by the client, leading to a scenario where you'd miss some "triggers". I don't know why you're looking to drop Quartz, but perhaps this will be of interest to you: http://redislabs.com/blog/run-quartz-the-java-job-scheduler-on-top-of-redis

Comment: Quartz is a scheduler, Redis is a key-value cache. They're not alternatives for each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I tried for solving couple of problems with redis cache expire. I used NodeJs insted.

But you have to maintain this logic even it expired for the next process and set the expiry time according to your business logic

```
redisCache.config('set','notify-keyspace-events','KEA');

redisCache.subscribe(`__keyevent@${process.env.REDIS_DATABASE}__:expired`);

redisCache.on('message',  (channel, key) => {
    /** 
      Logic
   */
});
```